# Wordpress complex meta_query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

`featured-home_duration = 2`,

`featured-home_start_date = 2015-10-16 00:00:00`

These two are `meta_keys` and values saved in my `post_meta table`.

I need to find posts. and they will be based on following formula .

`DATE_ADD({meta_value of featured-home_start_date} , INTERVAL {meta_value of featured-home_duration} DAY) > CURDATE()`

```
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => VA_LISTING_PTYPE,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'title menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => ? ? ? ,
            'value' => ? ? ? ,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    )
);
$listings = new WP_Query($args);
```

can any one help me in this??